# Laravel 5.1 Global scope

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a global scope that exclude deactivated users from query(1 - Activated, 0-Deactivated). But I have troubles with retrieving this deactivated users. I want to create a function that doing the same as `withTrashed()` method. But i cant figure out how. What should I write in remove method?

**UsersScope class**

```
class UsersScope implements ScopeInterface
{
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        return $builder->where('status', '=', 1);
    }

    public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I think it is straight forward here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#global-scopes

foreach ((array) $query->wheres as $key => $where)
    {
        // If the where clause is a soft delete date constraint, we will remove it from
        // the query and reset the keys on the wheres. This allows this developer to
        // include deleted model in a relationship result set that is lazy loaded.
        if ($this->isSoftDeleteConstraint($where, $column))
        {
            unset($query->wheres[$key]);

            $query->wheres = array_values($query->wheres);
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
public function remove(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{

    $query = $builder->getQuery();
    $query->wheres = collect($query->wheres)->reject(function ($where) {
        return $where['column'] = 'status';
    })
    ->values()->all();
}
```

Then use `withoutGlobalScope` method to remove the scope:

```
$users = User::withoutGlobalScope(UsersScope::class)->get();
```